PostgreSQL zero-or-one to zero-or-one relationship
As the title describes I want to have a zero-or-one to zero-or-one relationship.
For example, let's say we have two tables Calls and Files. A call might have an attached file on it, and vice versa. But I have a restriction. I want if I delete a call, its file be deleted too, but if I delete its file call should be remain as it is. Would something like this be possible with SQL Constraints (like ON DELETE CASCADE / ON DELETE SET NULL)? Or is there any way, implement such a behavior in database with SQL, without using trigger/events?
I tried something like below:
-- Create the 'files' table
CREATE TABLE files (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,  -- Primary key for the 'files' table
    file_name TEXT NOT NULL -- Any additional fields for the 'files' table
);

-- Create the 'calls' table
CREATE TABLE calls (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,  -- Primary key for the 'calls' table
    file_id INT UNIQUE,     -- Foreign key referencing 'files' table (1-1 relationship)
    call_description TEXT,  -- Any additional fields for the 'calls' table
    CONSTRAINT fk_file_id FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES files(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

-- Add an additional constraint on the 'files' table to enforce the cascading behavior
ALTER TABLE files
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_call_file
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES calls(file_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

but it requires to be deferrable as constraints are executed immediately. Also, it is not what I was intended. I want a call/file to exists without dependencies to each other.
What are the best practices to follow in such case?

I would choose the simple way:
CREATE TABLE calls
(   call_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    /* other fields */
);
CREATE TABLE files
(   file_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    call_id INT UNIQUE REFERENCES calls (call_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    /* other fields */
);

The calls table does not contain a reference to the files table. A row in the files table represents a file. If you delete a row in the calls table, the associated file will be automatically deleted. If you delete the file row, it will not affect the associated call row.
The UNIQUE constraint for call_id in files table eliminates the situation when several files are associated with one call.

I've prepared a complete dbfiddle for this solution, but now I am too lazy to write a full answer.  Add this to your answer if you want. https://dbfiddle.uk/Na0f_e6L

Hello @pvarouktsis the calls table does not contain a reference to the files table so you do not need to set NULL in it. A row in the files table represents a file, if you delete it, then again you don't need to set NULL anywhere. If you delete a row in the call table, the associated file will be automatically deleted.

@pvarouktsis added UNIQUE for call_id in files table. Because you don't want multiple files associated with one call.

@nik0x1 The place to explain the answer, is in the answer. Without merging your explanation and the demo into the post (the edit you just undid), it's incomplete and of questionable quality - posts are meant to be self-contained.

Thank you @Zegarek I added an explanation. The comments regarding NULL were a bit out of scope for the answer, so I answered in the comments. The demo had a different DDL, so I didn't include that either. I think now the example code and explanation answer the question.

I can think of multiple ways of doing this:

Invert the relationship if it makes sense so that Files reference Calls.
Use triggers
Just delete a file instead of the call and the file then will cascade to the call:

delete from files where id = (select file_id from calls where id = :call)


And if you don't want any cascades at all, you can just write multiple statements using a CTE (common table expression):

with deleted_calls as (
  delete from calls where id = :call
  returning (file_id)
)
delete from files where id = (select file_id from deleted_calls);

Note, that there are 2 queries to calls table. If we didn't have a FK, we could've first deleted the


Inverting the relationship, will, also, produce the same problem, but for setting null the call_id.
I would like to check if there's any possible solution without using triggers (just contraints).
We do not want that. We want a file to be deleted without affecting the call. If I want to delete a file, the call must be intact.
Same as (2)

Thanks for your response!

Would be there any possible solution for this problem using just constraints and tables? Maybe by creating another table call_file, referencing the file and call respectively.

Sorry for my mistake. (1) is misinterpreted by me! You are correct!
